# Angular - any way to return $index in ng-repeat faster?

Tags: angularjs

In my Angular app I have a button where I apply a CSS style depending on the `$index` from the ng-repeat.

However whats happening is on page load the buttons style appears as the default (which is class `button`) for a second before applying the actual style I want (which is `customColour{{$index}}`).

```
    <button type="button" ng-click="superAction($index)" 
                          class="small button customColour{{$index}}">
    </button>
```

I have confirmed that it must be down to the delay in getting the `$index` value having spent the last 4 hours playing around with the CSS files (ensuring things like my custom style appears at the top of my css file etc).

So any ideas/suggestions I can try would be appreciated.

Comment: add an `index` property to the objects you are going to repeat over.  don't rely upon `$index` for complex logic; it is error prone and the `$index` value could change and produce unexpected results.

Comment: Are you telking about the initial page load, which starts the application, or does it happen even when the application is already started and you switch to that page/route/state? If the former, use ng-cloak. If the latter, you must have a serious performance problem.

Comment: Create a demo that reproduces this. Have never seen any such delay myself unless perhaps you are rendering far too many rows or have other intensive digest processes going on

Comment: I actually have 2 ng-repeats - one within the other. My top most one I already use `track by $index` can I therefore track in the second one as well?

Comment: @charlietfl Here's a JSfiddle - its my first time using, I get an error on line 8 of the HTML its complaining about the `$index` - http://jsfiddle.net/yg8s1htd/

Comment: demo works fine for me in 2 browsers. No delay showing style

Comment: @charlietfl - i worked out what i effecting the performance - I'm showing  d3 chart when i remove this section of code everything is fine: `<div id="circle{{$index}}">
          <nvd3 options="circleOptions" data="detail.options"></nvd3>
        </div>`

Comment: Would have helped to mention something like that...all you showed was a simple button

Comment: I was trying to keep the fiddle simple - apologies - dont suppose you have any ideas on this? I'm thinking do the nvd3 bit once page loaded?